# how to install cucumber in cypress version 10

Tags: javascript, cucumber, cypress

I have seen many videos but unable to get exact installation of cucumber in cypress version 10

I want detailed step by step process for installation

Comment: You can refer - https://kailash-pathak.medium.com/how-to-integrate-cucumber-in-cypress-10-8c91033af9b7 , https://blog.emumba.com/getting-started-with-cypress-10-and-cucumber-6b43ff68633b

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.